# SVMs: where comes the 1 and -1 in hyperplane equations and where is b?

Tags: svm

Concering Support Vector Machines (SVM):
it is always mentioned that $\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i - b >= 1$, for $\textbf{x}_i$ of class 1 (i.e. $y=1$)
and  $\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i - b <= -1$, for  $\textbf{x}_i$ of class -1 (i.e. $y=-1$)
from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) I read that it is related to normalization of the dataset, so I guess all the  $\textbf{x}_i$ vectors are normalized (divided by) their norm ie  $\textbf{x}_i$ :=  $\textbf{x}_i/|| \textbf{x}_i||_2$ so they all have norm 1 and projecting i.e. doing the scalar product  $\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i$ would give someting lower than 1 or 1 if  $\textbf{w}$ was also normalized (which maybe it is not in general and so all this is not so clear?)

So I would like a detailed (don't hesitate to put all "so-called" "trivial" steps!) explanation of why this is so? Also if possible a geometric explanation/drawing.

Second question is about $b$. For a line in 2D it would represent the y-intercept (only if the w coefficient of the parameter corresponding to y in the vector w would be 1, otherwise need to divide b by it...) ... so i m not completely sure what distance it would be geometrically... can anyone draw this clearly? It's a shape that these specific points I mention seem to be always missing (or treated as "trivial" which they are not!) in any lectures I've seen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's -1 and +1 because the support vectors are normalized to ensure that the cases closest to the hyperplane have a distance of exactly 1. It's exactly one support vector distance from the plane.

The intercept of the plane is just the value of the plane if all features are zero (or absent). It does not have a practical meaning (except that it is negative if the mode is 0 and positive if it is 1) and is set to the point that ensures that the plane has exactly one SV distance from the closest cases and intersects the cases at the optimal point.

Answer (score 0):

The verbiage used in the Wikipedia article regarding the data set being "normalized" or "standardized" is confusing. Typically in machine learning, normalization of a data set is some sort of scaling of the observations or features before a learning algorithm is applied, e.g., scaling of each feature such that all feature values lie in [0, 1]. Or, the scaling of each observation such that their norms are 1, like the OP mentioned. But that's not what's happening in SVM.

If I were to write a detailed article on SVM, instead of saying that the data set is normalized, I'd say something like "without loss of generality." Meaning, if the classes are linearly separable, we can assume without loss of generality that we can find a hyperplane **wx** - b = 0 such that the value of |**wx** - b| is 1 for all support vectors.

This is because all support vectors are equidistant from the hyperplane, and
that distance is proportional to |**wx** - b|, based on [the formula for distance of a point from that hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane). The value of |**wx** - b| is the same for all support vectors. This means we can assign an arbitrary value to |**wx** - b|, and SVM solution will scale **w** and b accordingly to arrive at the same hyperplane.

By convention, |**wx** - b| is 1 for all support vectors.